# Does substitution failure disable static inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates

The following fails to compile under `GCC 4.8.1`:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A
{
    public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void foo(Args&&...)
    {
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    template <typename T>
    auto foo(T&& t) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, double>::value, void>::type
    {
    }
};


main()
{
    B b;
    b.foo(1.0);
    b.foo("string"); -> compiler error
}
```

The compiler error is:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:26:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::foo(const char [7])’
>      b.foo("string");
> ```

Why doesn't the second call to `foo()` resolve to call `A::foo`?

Comment: The name `foo` in class `B` hides the one declared in `A`. Insert a `using A::foo` statement to make it work.

Comment: @0x499602D2 why is this the case? If the function can't be resolved in `B`, shouldn't the compiler attempt to resolve it in the base class?

Comment: For the same reason that derived class functions and base class functions of the same name do not overload without a `using`.

Comment: It could, but for other reasons this behavior is not allowed.

Comment: Well it's good to learn :) Thanks!

Comment: *Name lookup* and *overload resolution* are separate; once a name is found in a scope then no more scopes are checked, and overload resolution is only done amongst instances of that name in the found scope, even if the name turned out to not work. Base class names are not injected into the derived class scope unless you specifically do so with `using`.

Comment: BTW, if `A::Foo` were visible `b.foo(1.0)` would be ambiguous.